# Trouble scraping titles from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python with selenium to parse some results populated upon filling in an inputbox and preessing the `Go` button. My script does this portion well at this moment. However, my main goal is to parse the title of that container visible as `Toys & Games` as well.

This is my try so far (`I could not find any idea to make a loop to do the same for all the containers`):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://www.fbatoolkit.com/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".estimator-container .estimator-input").send_keys("25000",Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(2)
item = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".estimator-result div").text
print(item)
driver.quit()
```

The result I get:

```
4 (30 Days Avg)
```

Result I would like to have:

```
Toys & Games
4 (30 Days Avg)
```

***[Link to an image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4zvpt09pus04na/Untitled.jpg?dl=0)*** in which you can see how they look like in that site. Expected fields are also marked with a pencil to let you know the location of the fields I'm trying to parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code to get required output

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = "https://www.fbatoolkit.com/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

for container in wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='chart-container']"))):
    wait(container, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.estimator-input"))).send_keys("25000", Keys.RETURN)
    title = wait(container, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".chart text"))).text
    item = wait(container, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".estimator-result div"))).text
    print(title, item)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Second chart? Which one?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov , it returns data for ALL charts on page

Comment: All of them (the content from all the charts) are perfectly coming through. You are the wizard sir Andersson!!

Comment: Why did you use `[class='chart-container']` like this sir? Was there another class with the same name as well?

Comment: `[class='chart-container']` means that we want to match node with this exact class name, so our CCS selector will not match the first chart (which is actually just a div with YouTube video) that has class names `"chart-container container_video"`. Note that CSS selector `".chart-container"` will match both types of chart